# What's wrong? Cannot load Microsoft RIFF/WAVE info

Tags: audio, wave, info, riff

/*
Sound info dump, from Stanford's Microsoft RIFF description/layout: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422-winter-2014/projects/WaveFormat/
*/

`$ git clone https://github.com/ETERNALBLUEbullrun/sounddemo.git && cd sounddemo

~/sounddemo $ ./run.sh

input: "input.wav", 3138126 == sz, 0x46464952 == inputHead == 'RIFF'; Microsoft RIFF. 3138118 == buffSz, 0x45564157 == format == 'WAVE'; Microsoft (WAV) sound.

16 == wave.Subchunk1Size, 2 == wave.NumChannels, 44100 == wave.SampleRate, 176400 == wave.ByteRate, 4 == wave.BlockAlign, 16 == wave.BitsPerSample, 1 == wave.AudioFormat; PCM. 26 == wave.Subchunk2Size,
5453494c == wave.Subchunk2ID, should == 'data'.

-1 == fread(inputBuff, 3138126, 1, 0xb400006f7d499d18)

~/sounddemo $`

Had uncompressed input.wav (not from repo,)

thought demo would parse all sound info.

Comment: Error = spec violation?
~/sounddemo $ git pull

~/sounddemo $ ./run.sh

Should './sound.so input.wav'. Input audio: input.wav

input: "input.wav", 3138126 == sz, 0x46464952 == inputHead == 'RIFF'; Microsoft RIFF. 3138118 == buffSz, 0x45564157 == format == 'WAVE'; Microsoft (WAV) sound.
16 == wave.Subchunk1Size, 2 == wave.NumChannels, 44100 == wave.SampleRate, 176400 == wave.ByteRate, 4 == wave.BlockAlign, 16 == wave.BitsPerSample, 1 == wave.AudioFormat; PCM. 26 == wave.Subchunk2Size,
5453494c == wave.Subchunk2ID, should == 'data'.

-1 == fread(buffer, 3138126, 1, 0xb400007847664c58)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To load MS wav/riff, to know howto construct sounds